# Will the 1140px CSS Grid System work if I need to keep the middle of my site always there - in the middle?

Tags: asp.net, css, bing-maps, asp.net-webpages

I need to create a site (one page of original content) that will be, if I use the 1140px/12 column system (http://cssgrid.net/), 3 columns on the left, 6 in the middle, and 3 on the right.

The left strip will contain controls, probably mainly a Treeview.

The "vast" middle section will be a Bing Map.

When viewed on a phone or tablet, I need the map to remain fixed as the centerpiece.

Will this work with the 1140/12 project, or should I look in another direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start from creating sample layout so we can be sure that we speak about the same thing there. Basic layout for 3+6+3 grid will be:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="threecol"></div>
        <div class="sixcol"></div>
        <div class="threecol"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is 3 div's that have `width` set in percents and `float: left;` applied to show them side buy side. Then you resize window to width that is less then 768px media query starts to work. This media query will remove float from columns and make them occupy 100% of width each.

So short answer is not, middle column will not stay at the center of the screen, it will be pushed under left column that will occupy 100% of screen width, and will also occupy 100% of screen width. Third column will be also pushed under 2nd and occupy 100% of width.

If you just need to leave map at the top of the other columns to be seen first, I suggest to write media query that will hide left column on phones and open it  onclick in lightbox then users will need it.

If you need to have them on the same screen side by side, you probably will need to write your own classes for your grid.

Comment: Thanks; do I need to add "rows" here, too, to allow for a footer, or is that a separate animal?

Comment: "row" class is used to make a group from the grid columns — it's make sure that content that comes after them didn't broke, because of columns different height or other factors. If you footer have 100% width and didn't have columns, then you didn't need to use this class. But if you have columns in your footer, then it's better to use it.